# ¿Hay alguna diferencia importante entre los dos subjuntivos?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Estoy encantado con estas dos formas del lenguaje, pero ninguno de los materiales disponibles ha clarificado la diferencia entre las dos formas:

> Si **hubiese** sabido que iba a llover, me habría quedado en casa.
>
> Si **hubiera** sabido que iba a llover, me habría quedado en casa.

Las formas simultáneas de todas las lenguas que conozco llevan diferencias, por lo menos en estilo, y tengo la intuición de que el castellano no haga ninguna excepción de las reglas universales, pero ¿cómo se distinguen las dos formas del subjuntivo salvo la antigüedad prevaleciente de las formas con el s?

Comment: +1 buena pregunta

Answer (score 6):

El imperfecto de subjuntivo tiene dos conjugaciones posibles, pero las dos son válidas y equivalentes. Es decir, las dos significan exactamente lo mismo y pueden ser intercambiadas, no hay ninguna distinción.

En tu ejemplo, por tanto, los dos verbos significan lo mismo:

> Sí hubiera/hubiese sabido que iba a llover, me habría quedado en casa.

Puedes elegir cualquiera de las dos formas, la que más te guste ;)

Comment: Algunos opinan que "-ra" se utiliza más a menudo actualmente. Me atrevería a decir incluso que las formas con "-se" se utilizan más en contextos formales, pero esto no significa en absoluto que uno sea formal y el otro informal.

Comment: Me parece que en una frase que contenga dos verbos imperfectos de subjuntivo lo más común es que uno acabe en -ase/-iese y el otro -ara/-iera.